How to remove all unit separator code inside a string all 13 of them
I got a string that look like this
'deFG4209268392612927005702000004809357'

there are unit seperator code inside that string, in vs code it look like this

and sublime text, it look like this

I want to remove anything look like that in the string. what the proper regex for that ?

Sounds like a skill issue. The text should be cleaned up, if part of source code.

I got a noti this quesiton is being closed because it' duplicate quesiton, I check the other question, the answer is wrong for my case.  why stackoverflow close this question?

How is it wrong? Please edit the question to point out how the dupe doesn't solve your problem
